# sonar stops immediately after starting in AWS Ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, sonarqube

I have setup Sonarqube in my Ec2 earlier using java version 1.8 and it was running fine. Now also I am using java 1.8 for this. I have configured sonarqube by making a user in root in ec2 and inside opt folder I have configured everything for it. Now its not working. I am using ./sonar.sh start for starting the sonarqube in it.After sometime when I check the status of sonar it shows its not running.
Attaching the screenshot for the same.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBjlC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sonar Sever will not work with root account as it uses elastic search. Therefore, the service will stop as you as you run the start command. You can go to logs and see the error.

[Log files shows the root cause for the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meC5z.png)

Create a normal user to start sonar server. If you are using ubuntu, you can use ubuntu user or create a new one.

Once user is created, sonar.sh file and search for RUN_AS_USER parameter.

[set your non root user in sonar.sh file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeYRO.png)

check the ownership of sonar directory as follows:

[check sonar directory ownership](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvwRi.png)

If package is not installed, ru below command to install ACL.

[access control list installation on ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcwqr.png)

Change the ownership of directory/ sub dir as follows:

[change ownership of directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGs39.png)

Restart sonar server as follows:

[start sonar server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0lvk.png)

Get the status after start

[check the status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RKZD.png)

Finally, Go to your network settings in EC@ and open port 9000.